# Header tag error in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my application I am getting this error:

> You can only have one <head runat="server"> control on a page.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: You can only have one  control on a page.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Post stack trace, and which control causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are  having problem with `<head runat="server">` tag, and you are using master pages...

if you are using master pages, do not use `<head runat="server">` inside child page... you can add necessary header tags in

> `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
>   </asp:Content>`

if you do not have any master page, then make sure whether `<head runat="server">` tag is not repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one `<form runat="server">` tags on your page? You can only have one of these.

Comment: ya i solve that problem actually two <header runat="server"> are there now it is working thank you for response